# Batch Paypal Payments

Tags: python, django, paypal

Can you send a paypal payment with a script?  I've been googling for this, but I can't seem to find the answer I want (yes) ;-)

An example of what I am talking about:  Lets say I have a site where users share in the profit.  Instead of sending each users payment out manually at the end of the month, I would like to automate this with code, preferably django / python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  This page may help:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_masspay

Clarification edit:
Basically you use the mass-pay API call.  However, even though it's called mass pay, I believe you can send payments to just one person with it.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the [Paypal API documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference)

Comment: Good link, I've used the NVP before to create and get recurring payments, but didn't know about the "do" side of it.  I should of thought to look at this page before asking this question :-(